# redirect to ftp server while hiding username/password?

Tags: php, mysql, ftp

I am currently using this to redirect to an ftp server

```
header('Location: ' . $result['url']);
```

the `$result['url']` contains ftp urls like this

```
ftp:username@password:server
```

the problem is that anyone can open the console and see the security creds,

I know that you can hide an download url by using readfile like so

```
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Length: " .(string)(filesize($variable)) );
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($variable).'"');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\n");
readfile($variable);
```

is there something similar for ftp url redirects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: it's not possible

Long answer: it's not possible at all. Even if it was possible - then anyway, what would be passed to the client is easy to discovery, thus insecure.